# How to print the result from gensim.models.Word2Vec

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec

I would like to see the result from the word embeddings model, the vectors results.

When using the following code:

```
words_embeddings = gensim.models.Word2Vec(all_sentences, size=96, window=5, min_count=1, workers=2, sg=1)
print(words_embeddings)
```

I get the following output:

```
Word2Vec(vocab=9700, size=96, alpha=0.025)
```

I am wondering if the `gensim` library as a method to display the result form `gensim.models.Word2Vec()`

Comment: What kind of 'result' do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need train your model. After then, in order to get word vector, you can use:

```
print(words_embeddings.wv[word])
```

Comment: I thought that the model was already trained using the `Word2Vec` algorithm and the the data from `all_sentances` I thought an untrained model looks like this: `model = gensim.models.Word2Vec()`

Comment: You can do `print(gensim.models.Word2Vec())`, too. It will just print a summary of the model you've just created with all-default parameters that hasn't yet been configured with a vocabulary or trained. If you try just `'print(model)` on your untrained `model`, what is missing from the printout that you wanted to see?

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking for the vocabulary of words your model created:

```
model_keys = your_model_name.wv.key_to_index
print(sorted([w for w in model_keys]))
```

otherwise please refer to https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/keyedvectors.html#gensim.models.keyedvectors.CompatVocab